# Make legend invisible but keep figure dimensions and margins the same

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a plot with a legend.

[image]

Using an image editing program I made the legend invisible (but otherwise the figure has the same dimensions)

[image]

Is it possible to do this in ggplot2? I want to have a 2x2 panel of diagrams in a document but only one legend.

Comment: "I want to have a 2x2 panel of diagrams in a document but only one legend." Usually the answer to this is faceting. Why can't you use that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using this as an example,

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, color = factor(cyl))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

The following seems to work:

```
p + theme(
        legend.text = element_text(color = "white"),
        legend.title = element_text(color = "white"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")
    ) + 
    scale_color_discrete(
        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "white"))
    )
```

[image]

Notice that the dimension of the gray plot area did not change.

Answer (score 3):

Making the elements just white could cause problems, i.e. in cases of continuous scales or so. One may makes the scales and text elements just invisible.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, lty = factor(gear))) +
          geom_point(aes(color = cyl)) +
          geom_line()
```

Gives a normal plot with legend:

[image]

Now make it really "invisible" by setting `alpha = 0` in `override.aes = list()` within the  `guide = guide_legend()` argument for each of the scales and `color = "transparent"`  for the text elements of the legend:

```
p + scale_color_continuous(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0) ) )+
scale_linetype(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0) ) )+
theme(legend.title = element_text(color = "transparent"),
    legend.text = element_text(color = "transparent"))
```

[image]