# Align x axis with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot two aligned graphics, but one of them has a label and of them doesn't.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <-
  seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-31"), by = 1) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(day = value) %>%
  mutate(
    x = seq(1, 31, by = 1),
    y = x * 2 - 20
  )

p1 <-
  df %>%
  gather(key, value, c(x, y)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line(size = 1)

p2 <-
  df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = y / x)) +
  geom_line(size = 1)

grid.arrange(
  p1, p2
)
```

Result:

[image]

Is there a way to align the axis **without using facet_wrap**? (I want to add specific label formatters for each plot because they are in different units and facet_wrap doesn't allow me to do that as far as I know)

Comment: Is removing the legend from first plot an option? How about adding a legend to the second plot?

Comment: It is an option I want to avoid (unless we can create a completely blank legend at the second plot)

Comment: How about putting the legend in a different position, for ex. `theme(legend.position="bottom")`?

Comment: The plots aren't still totally aligned when I do that because of the y axis labels.

Comment: Adding blank legend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438450/make-legend-invisible-but-keep-figure-dimensions-and-margins-the-same-in-ggplot2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manage them as different plots, with same legend, using `cowplot` package:

```
library(cowplot)
legend <- get_legend(p1)   # get the legend of the first one plot

# here the plots in a grid
prow <- plot_grid( p1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
           # here you add the percentage
           p2 + theme(legend.position="none")+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent),
           align = 'v',
           labels = c("A", "B"),
           hjust = -1,
           nrow = 2)

# here you add the legend
p <- plot_grid( prow, legend, rel_widths = c(3, .3))
p
```

[image]