# How to remove the legend or make transparent while keeping its space in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question has been answered here: [Make legend invisible but keep figure dimensions and margins the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438450/make-legend-invisible-but-keep-figure-dimensions-and-margins-the-same) and [Make legend invisible but keep figure dimensions and margins the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438450/make-legend-invisible-but-keep-figure-dimensions-and-margins-the-same), but the solutions provided do not work for me so far. The aim is to make the legend invisible or white while keeping the space it takes in the graph.

I still get the outer box lines of the legend on the right, and I am not sure how to remove them. Can someone help please?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(l, aes(x=year, y=annual_chg, fill=income,color=income)) +
  geom_col(position = "identity", alpha = 1/2,colour= "black") +  
  facet_wrap(~Class,nrow=1)+
  theme_classic()+xlab(NULL)+ylab(NULL)+
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(color = "white"),
    legend.title = element_text(color = "white"),
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes= list(alpha = 0)),
         colour = guide_colorbar(override.aes = list(alpha=0)))
```

Here is the data:

```
df=structure(list(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
                            2018), annual_chg = c(-0.66, 0.34, 0.59, 1.54, -0.26, 0.49, 0.66, 
                                                  1.62), Class = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Upper-middle class", 
                                                                                                                         "Middle class", "Skilled working class", "Low-skilled working class"
                                                  ), class = "factor"), income = c("gross income", "gross income", 
                                                                                   "gross income", "gross income", "net income", "net income", "net income", 
                                                                                   "net income")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                     "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make legend invisible but keep figure dimensions and margins the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438450/make-legend-invisible-but-keep-figure-dimensions-and-margins-the-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `theme(legend.key=element_rect(colour="white"))`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=annual_chg, fill=income,color=income)) +
  geom_col(position = "identity", alpha = 1/2,colour= "black") +  
  facet_wrap(~Class,nrow=1)+
  theme_classic()+xlab(NULL)+ylab(NULL)+
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(color = "white"),
    legend.title = element_text(color = "white"),
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes= list(alpha = 0, color = "white"))) +
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(colour="white"))
```

[image: white legend]